# how to use angular 5 to build chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension using angular 5.
I created a basic angular app using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) and it worked great as an angular app (I used `ng build` to check).
I tried to move the application to be a chrome extension so I used `ng build` to create the code and I added the following manifest

```
{
   "name": "Getting Started Example",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Build an Extension!",
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["runtime.js","polyfills.js","styles.js","vendor.js","main.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
       "default_popup": "index.html"
     },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

the background scripts are the scripts the angular compiler created and are used to render the app.
I upload my extension but I got this error

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
>   'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob:
>   filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

what does it mean? how can I run my angular application as a chrome extension?

Comment: https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/build-your-own-chrome-extension-using-angular-4-ecedbd7404cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to add JS files in the script just add reffernce of index.html file of your dist folder 
It will automatically add all required JS/CSS files from there.

so Just remove this line of code

```
"scripts": ["runtime.js","polyfills.js","styles.js","vendor.js","main.js"],
```

For more information refer here -

- https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/build-your-own-chrome-extension-using-angular-4-ecedbd7404cc

Comment: I did referenced it in default_popup,where else should I?

Comment: actually the link you gave me worked,thanks .I added "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'", and it worked

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this line to the manifest.json for that error to go away:

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

and remove the following line of code, because that isn't needed:

```
"scripts": ["runtime.js","polyfills.js","styles.js","vendor.js","main.js"]
```

To setup a proper workflow is a different story. Every time you make a change you need to rebuild the project manually. This can be some what of a hassle.

I have created a CLI to support such a workflow (auto watch files, build for production and zip it etc)

see: https://github.com/larscom/ng-chrome-extension for more information.